# Relationship between code length and predicted distribution

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

## Problem

In a video I just watched (as could be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErfnhcEV1O8), between 7:10 - 7:30), the author claims that the number of digits one uses to encode a particular weather condition reflects his/her prediction about the weather distribution. For example, if two digits are used, then he/she believes the probability of that weather condition is $\frac{1}{2^2}=0.25$. Similarly, if five digits are used, then the probability should be $\frac{1}{2^5}=0.03125$.

As much as I could understand this from high level, i.e. if something happens quite often, then using fewer digits will surely save your transmission cost. However, I do not understand the mathematical reasoning of this correspondence between number of digits in a code and probability of a particular event.

I do not have previous exposure to information theory, so could someone provide some pointer for this question? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find the example in the video very illuminating. Perhaps a better (and classical example) is the old [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code). You need to encode the 26 letters using sequences of dots and dashes (which could be thought as 0/1 bits), not necessarily of the same length.
If you think a little about this, you'll probably realize the same fact that the designer (around 1837!) realized: the more frequent (more probable) letters should get the shorter codes.

Actually, this happens also in most natural languages: the most frequent words tend to be shorter. We quickly guess that this is more efficient.

Matematically: if we have symbols $s_1, s_2 \cdots s_n$ and we want to encode them with codes of lengths $\ell_1 , \ell_2 \cdots \ell_n$, then the average code lenght (per symbol) is

$$L= \sum p(s_i) \, \ell_i$$

where $p(s_i)$ is the probability of symbol $i$. We want $L$ to be as small as possible.
For this, we'd want $\ell_i$ to be small, but we cannot make all of them too small because the code, to be usable (decodable), obsviously impose some restrictions (if you are curious about this, see [Kraft's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality)).  Then, it makes (mathematical and intuitive) sense that the higher probabilities should be associated with smaller lengthts.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about Huffman codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding